# Parsing JSON url in Java

Tags: java, parsing, gson, json

I am trying to parse some JSON data to Java using GSON but I am unable to do so due to the way it is formatted. I've looked around a lot but none of the information I found helped me work this out. I haven't had much experience with JSON, especially when parsing it to Java. I would appreciate any help I get for this.

JSON URL:
http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/status.json

EDIT:

I took your advise about using Jackson and went through some guides and tried making it, Heres my code:

Main Class: http://pastebin.com/XRcpkAuP

UptimeCheck Class: pastebin/f2UanvhY (Sorry, I couldnt post more than 2 links :/)

For some reason, It doesnt seem to be able to parse the link. Could someone please help me out?
Thank You

Comment: What do you mean by "due to the way it is formatted"? Ultimately, why is it failing?

Comment: can u share the coed and exact problem

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ shows that to be valid json.

Comment: Please do not "hide" content away at pastebin. Include it directly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally recommend to use Jackson to convert JSON to/from Java. Jackson is a High-performance JSON processor Java library.

Below snippets would give a basic idea to this library.

```
//1. Convert JSON to Java object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\report_data.json"), ReportData.class);

//2. Convert Java object to JSON format
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\report_data.json"), reportData);
```

Both `writeValue()` and `readValue()` has many overloaded methods to support different type of `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.

Example for your reference: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Shishir

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about gson, but your JSON String is valid. You can use the following:

This is simple code to do it, I avoided all checks but this is the main idea.

```
 public String parse(String jsonLine) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
    JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("data");
    JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("translations");
    jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    String result = jobject.get("translatedText").toString();
    return result;
}
```

To make the use more generic - you will find that the [javadoc][1] of this are pretty clear and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I read it in another article.. Using GSON seems to be good....

Simplest thing usually is to create matching Object hierarchy, like so:

This is an example

```
public class Wrapper {
   public Data data;
}
static class Data {
   public Translation[] translations;
}
static class Translation {
   public String translatedText;
}
```

and then bind using GSON, traverse object hierarchy via fields. Adding getters and setters is pointless for basic data containers.

So something like:

```
Wrapper value = GSON.fromJSON(jsonString, Wrapper.class);
String text = value.data.translations[0].translatedText;
```

Comment: You do realize Stackoverflow is not a forum with conversation threads; there's little reason to post a brand new answer (barely a minute after your previous), when you can simply edit your original answer with the updated information.

Comment: @PaulRichter It is not necessary that a question should have only one answer. If both of my answers are similar i could have edited, but here 1 is with GSON and another is without GSON. So i don't think i should have edited, more over then why stack overflow is allwing a user to post more than 1 answer for a question ?

Comment: Its a moot point now, since I see you removed the other answer. The main issue was that both answers were very general. While they were not "wrong" (and you were trying to be helpful), neither were they "correct" in terms of the OPs question, because we simply did not have enough information in order to give a specific and concise answer. Ultimately, double answers themselves are avoided unless both posts are clearly *distinct*, and even then, its not encouraged because usually such situations are a good indication that the question itself might be too general (and may need to be closed).